# What does the overline mean in this: "What is the order of $\overline{30}$ in $\Bbb Z/54\Bbb Z$?"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

I apologize if this was posted already somewhere. I looked but had trouble describing it. My only question is what the overline means in this situation. I do not need help with the actual problem.

What is the order of $\overline{30}$ in $\Bbb Z/54\Bbb Z$?

Comment: The overline probably denotes that it is equivalence class modulo 54 to avoid confusion with the integer 30.

Comment: I am confused then because the second part of the question asks: Write all of the elements of $\langle \overline{30} \rangle$.

Comment: By equivalence classes modulo 54 are just the elements of $\mathbb{Z}/54\mathbb{Z}$. For example, $\overline{30} + \overline{30} = \overline{6}$ whereas $30 + 30 = 60$.

Comment: @User52525:  That's fine, here are a few members of $\overline{30}$:  $30$, $84$, $-24$.

Comment: Ahh thank you I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $\overline{30} = \left[30\right] =\left\{54m+30 \ : \ m\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$